# How to mock fetch function inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is how my function inside the `useEffect` hook looks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getImages = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(GET_RECENT_IMAGES_API_URL(pageNumber));

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        const imageData = await response.json();

        setIsLoading(false);

        const appImaegDataArray: CoreImageData[] = imageData.photos.photo.map(
          (image: ResponseImageData) => {
            const { id, server, secret, title, ownername } = image;

            const coreImageDataObj: CoreImageData = {
              id,
              server,
              secret,
              title,
              ownername,
              isFavorite: checkIfFavorited(id),
            };

            return coreImageDataObj;
          }
        );
        setAllImages((prevAllImagesState) => {
          const newestImagesArray = [
            ...prevAllImagesState,
            ...appImaegDataArray,
          ];
          return getUniqueImagesArray(newestImagesArray);
        });

        setHasMore(imageData.photos.pages > pageNumber);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getImages();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [pageNumber]);
```

Here is my approach for mocking the request:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () =>
      Promise.resolve({
        photos: {
          pages: 10,
          photo: [
            {
              id: "51159068217",
              owner: "50123236@N03",
              secret: "dda285148c",
              server: "65535",
              farm: 66,
              title: "Blythe a Day May 5–Magical",
              ispublic: 1,
              isfriend: 0,
              isfamily: 0,
            },
          ],
        },
      }),
  })
) as jest.Mock;

describe("<ImageList />", () => {
  it("loads all images on mount", async () => {
    render(<ImageList isViewFavoriteImages={false} />);
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.getByText("Blythe a Day May 5–Magical")).toBeInTheDocument()
    );
  });
});
```

However, when doing this, I get an error and the test fails. Here is the output for the failed test:
[image]

What would be the best approach to fix the test?

Answer (score 0):

```js
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => ({
  json: ...,
  ok: true,
  status: 200,
})
```

Although I would advise [not to mock fetch](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch/). Instead extract that to a service method and mock that..?

```
// my-service.js

export const fetchFoo = () => {
  return fetch(...)
}

// my-test.spec.js

jest.mock('./my-service', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('some-value'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, could you explain in more detail how should I refactor the functions? I'm asking, because I don't know what to do with the `setLoading` and  `setHasMore`, because they directly depend on what is happening inside of the `getImages` function.

Comment: `getImages` can be tested as it is, no real need to refactor (although you could clean it up a bit by extracting some logic to methods in order to make it more readable) the original test was failing because `fetch` was not mocked properly, if you move the logic to a service and mock that service it should work